# autofilling textboxes with database data based on a primary key entry into another textbox

Tags: vb.net

i have the code below, it works fine but whenever i insert a student number that does not exist in the table, the rest of the textboxes will keep displaying data from the previous existing entry. This happens even when the i delete everything in the student number textbox.
how can i change it such that the rest of the textboxes are cleared in case the student number textbox is blank or contains a student number that does not exist in the database?
Thanks in advance.

```
    '  Try

    Dim mycommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

    Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = Nothing

    myconnection.Open()

    Dim query As String

    query = " select StudentNo,Fullname,Year,Term,Class from StudentRegistration  where StudentNo = '" & TxtStudentNo.Text & "' and (class = 'Senior 5A' or Class ='Senior 5S' or Class='Senior 6A' or class='Senior1 6S')"
    mycommand = New SqlCommand(query, myconnection)
    datareader = mycommand.ExecuteReader()
    While datareader.Read
        If datareader IsNot Nothing Then
            '    TxtStudentNo.Text = datareader.Item("StudentNo")
            TxtName.Text = datareader.Item("FullName")
            TxtYear.Text = datareader.Item("Year")
            TxtTerm.Text = datareader.Item("Term")
            TxtClass.Text = datareader.Item("Class")
        End If

    End While
    myconnection.Close()
    ' Catch ex As Exception
    'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    ' End Try`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an else condition to reader and clear text boxes in that module.

```
 While datareader.Read
        If datareader IsNot Nothing Then
            '    TxtStudentNo.Text = datareader.Item("StudentNo")
            TxtName.Text = datareader.Item("FullName")
            TxtYear.Text = datareader.Item("Year")
            TxtTerm.Text = datareader.Item("Term")
            TxtClass.Text = datareader.Item("Class")
        else 
            TxtName.Text = ""
            TxtYear.Text = ""
            TxtTerm.Text = ""
            TxtClass.Text = ""
        End If
```

hope theres no big deal more than this.

Comment: thanks but i tried that already and it is not working, it seems the 'else condition' is not being run because i deliberately put code that would bring a runtime error but the program was run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally changed my code to the one below and it's doing exactly what i want.

```
    Private Sub getData()
       Dim dt As New DataTable()
    myconnection.Open()

    Dim Mycommand As New SqlCommand("select Fullname,Year,Term,Class from StudentRegistration  where StudentNo = '" & TxtStudentNo.Text & "'", myconnection)
    Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(Mycommand)
    sqlDa.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        TxtName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("FullName").ToString()
        TxtYear.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Year").ToString()
    Else
        TxtName.Text = ""
        TxtYear.Text = ""
    End If
    myconnection.Close()
End Sub
```